# How to make multimedia keys useful in KDE

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde-4

In Gnome when I pressed the "play" button on my keyboard it would play/pause the song in a media player.

In KDE when I press the play button nothing happens.

I want to use this key to send a play/pause signal message to the program "mpc" so that when I press the key it does the same thing as typing "mpc toggle" in a terminal.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the keyboard type in KDE System Settings / Hardware / Input Devices / Keyboard, tab Hardware, Keyboard model?
If yes and still nothing happens, you might need to configure the action triggered by the key in System Settings / Common Appearance and Behaviour / Shortcuts and Gestures / Custom Shortcuts.

Comment: there is no "input devices" here, any idea? only "display and monitor" and "digital camera" under hardware